# Handling Static Collections in Java

Tags: java, collections, static, hashmap

say I have a class A which is as follows

```
    public class A {
      protected static float[] floatArray = null;
      protected static Map<Integer, float[]>  history = new HashMap<Integer,float[]>();
      protected static Integer historyCount = 0;

      public void runEverySecond(Populator objPopulator) {
         floatArray = objPopulator.getValues();
         history.put(historyCount, floatArray);
         historyCount++;
      }  
    }
```

and Class B looks as follows

```
    public class B {
      private A objA;
      protected final static Populator objPopulator = new Populator();

      public void run(Integer numOfTime) {
        for(int i = 0; i < numOfTime; i++)
           objA.runEverySecond(objPopulator);
      }
    }
```

and Class Populator looks as follows

```
    public class Populator {
      protected float[] randomValues = new float[2];
      public float[] getValues() {
        randomValues[0] = //some new random float value generated for every call
        randomValues[1] = //some new random float value generated for every call
        return randomValues;
      }
    }
```

and class containing main looks as follows

```
    public class MainClass {
      public static void main() {
        final B objB = new B();
        objB.run(10);
      }
    }
```

Here is the problem I am facing, the Map history contains the same value for every entry in the map. I want the Map history to store all the values generated by objPopulator.getValues() method. How do I do it?

Some help would be really appreciable.
Thanks in Advance :)

The Actual code (with irrelevant code removed ) represented by class A

```
public class MySuperAgent implements Agent {
protected static float[] marioFloatPos = null;
protected static Map<Integer, float[]> levelRecord = new HashMap<Integer, float[]>();
protected static Integer mapCount = 0;
/*  protected static int testCount = 0;
protected static float[] testx = new float[2];
protected static float[] testy = new float[2];*/

@Override
public void integrateObservation(Environment environment) {
    marioFloatPos = environment.getMarioFloatPos();
    levelRecord.put(mapCount, marioFloatPos);
    mapCount++;

   /*if(testCount < 2){
        testx[testCount] = marioFloatPos[0];
        testy[testCount] = marioFloatPos[1];
        testCount++;
    } else {
        testCount = 0;
    }*/
  }
}
```

class C represent environment object
integrateObservation method is called from class similar to class B
if I use the code within the comment block then I am able to record only 2 past values of x and y of Mario. I need a way to store all the values of x and y of Mario :)

Comment: Myself, I wouldn't be dealing with all those statics in the first place.

Comment: There are these things called "references" in Java, "pointers" in other languages.  They are wonderful things if you know how to use them.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: haha.. yes all those statics are really messed up.. unfortunately I cannot change the code in this class because there are other number of classes which are using theses values and I cannot change code in those classes because I am not allowed to :(..

Comment: @HotLicks: yes references are good but I cannot change code in other classes which I am not responsible for :)

Comment: @Pazuzu: You might want to propose a more flexible code ownership process to your team: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CodeOwnership.html
Of course, you still have to make sure to address backwards compatibility issues.

Comment: @Puce: Thank you for the valuable link. I am not working in a team or anything. I am writing an Agent for gameplay track for an IEEE CIG mario ai competition and to enter the competition I have to submit my code which uses their code and I cannot change their code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one `floatArray` and you keep reassigning it.

This code was almost impossible to follow in a reasonable way--what a mess.

Comment: Hi Dave Newton, Thanks for your reply, I know the code is a mess, but this is just a sample representing the real code which is even more messed up :D.. unfortunately I am not allowed to modify the classes which I am not responsible for :(. I am only responsible for class A and I cannot have more than one floatArray :(. is there anyway I can store the history of all the output from Populator class?

Comment: @Pazuzu You'll need to be more specific--if the code you're calling is *actually* returning a new array, using a local will work fine.

Comment: The code I am calling does not return a new array, it only modifies the previous values of the array. Is it because of this the previous values in the HashMap are getting changed?

Comment: @Pazuzu If it doesn't create a new array then you need to copy it into a new array. If what you're saying is true, the question is a bit misleading because it shows the code you're calling creating a new array.

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes in the code. I have corrected them now. I tried your suggestion and it works perfect now :D.. thank you, your awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

Every entry in your `Map` has a reference to the same static field `floatArray` as its value.

Instead of having `floatArray` as a static member variable in `A` consider:

```
  public void runEverySecond(Populator objPopulator) {
     float[] floatArray = objPopulator.getValues();
     history.put(historyCount, floatArray);
     historyCount++;
  }
```

**EDIT** Also I don't know how your code for class `A` would compile as it is. Shouldn't `runEverySecond` take a `Populator` parameter instead of `Object`? See revised snippet above.

Comment: Hi milkplusvellocet, Thanks for your reply. This is not the actual code, it is just a sample code of the real thing, and thank you for pointing out the mistake I made in class A :), yes you are correct it should be Populator and not Object. Anyway I tried your suggestion out and the results are still the same :(. I just want to know how I can maintain the history of generated values. Instead of using the HashMap if I use an normal array, say of size 2, in my sample code the history is recorded properly, but only for last 2 generations. I need a way to store all the generations :)

Comment: I've just tried this and it works exactly as expected. Could you post _actual_ code, including the changes you've made after I answered? Then we can help you out more.

Comment: Please have a look at the kind of actual code above. Thanks for the help

Comment: You haven't implemented the change I originally suggested. Instead of `marioFloatPos` being a static member variable of `MySuperAgent` you should declare it as a local variable inside the `integrateObservation` method. So the line would be `float[] marioFloatPos = environment.getMarioFloatPos();`

Comment: I tried exactly the same thing.. the previously stored values in the map are all changed to the last value inserted in the map. and sorry for not posting your changes I thought that would be confusing for new readers.

Comment: I think Dave Newton might be correct. Please correct me if I am wrong. Since the HashMap will have the references of array stored and the not the real values and the method I call does not return a new array but instead returns a modified version of the same array. So the values of the previously stored entries in the HashMap gets changed because HashMap only has references.

Comment: Yes he's correct if that's the case. This is why it's **essential** to post accurate samples of your code when you ask a question. You'll need a new `Array` each time or every entry will still be pointing to the same underlying object.

Comment: Yes now it works. Here is the actual code which works float[] marioFloatPos = new float[2]; marioFloatPos[0] = environment.getMarioFloatPos()[0]; marioFloatPos[1] = environment.getMarioFloatPos()[1]; Thanks for the help :)